# ORDER BY SUM() not working on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This seems like a really basic query, which works fine on my desktop, but the results are not ordered when executing on Android:

```sql
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) AS column3 
FROM ftdata WHERE ftdata MATCH 'column1:example'
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY SUM(column2) DESC
LIMIT 8
```

I've also tried wrapping this in an inner table to no avail:

```sql
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) AS column3 
FROM ftdata WHERE ftdata MATCH 'column1:example'
GROUP BY column1) X
ORDER BY X.column3 DESC
LIMIT 8
```

This is the code I'm using to run the query in case it helps:

```java
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        results.add(c.getString(0));
    }
    while(c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```

I should also clarify that `ftdata` is a virtual table used for FTS querying. Its definition is as follows:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ftdata USING fts3(
column1,
column2 int)
```

Comment: What is `results`? How do you check its order?

Comment: `results` is an `ArrayList<String>`. I am inspecting it through the debugger and also it outputs to screen. I know which order it should be in as I'm comparing it to the desktop dataset. I am starting to think it's because `freq` is an `int` column in my FTS table and it's treating it as a string

Comment: In your queries, you are not using `freq` at all.

Comment: Heh, that's what I get for using example names ;) Let me update the code. `freq` in my table is really `column2`, i.e. the column to be `SUM`d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) AS my_sum 
FROM ftdata WHERE ftdata MATCH 'column1:example'
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY my_sum DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: I said before this doesn't work. It does. I just need to deploy my changes when I check. *facepalm*